# imacros javascript coding for JS form

Tags: javascript, imacros

best regards ,

I have been using imacros for 2 weeks and I love it, 
my problem is, I have this website form [alibaba](http://message.alibaba.com/msgsend/contact.htm?action=contact_action&domain=2&id=213586652)

I can automate all the form and checkbox except the "Message" one,

I have written many JS codes and try to write using id, class

but nothing worked

I have tested all the demos and they worked

I use windows xp sp2, my browser firefox 13.0.1, my imacro addon 7.5.0.4

could you kindly help my ,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That message `input` box is in fact hidden (I don't think Imacros can change the attribute of a DOM element; try using javascript inside `EVAL` or better make a Greasemonkey script). As I've seen in that message box you actually write inside an Iframe overlapped on that `textarea`. You can access that in Imacros but not do much about with: `FRAME F=3`.